# Keep model updated when changing inputs with an external plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a directive that wraps the [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) plugin. It is mostly working, but I want the directive to be as compatible with other code as possible and it looks like it will not update a model that is attached to an input if it is being changed via the plugin.

I have tried calling $apply and $digest so that the scope might try to update, but the value in the model isn't changing.

The directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('skinned', function () {// Might need to cover all radios
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope   : {
            skinned       : '@',
            skinnedInsert : '@'
        },
        link    : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var inputs = elem.find('input');

            var checkboxClass = 'icheckbox';
            var radioClass = 'iradio';

            if (scope.skinned) {
                checkboxClass += '_' + scope.skinned;
                radioClass    += '_' + scope.skinned;
            }

            var options = {
                cursor        : true,
                checkboxClass : checkboxClass,
                radioClass    : radioClass,
                insert        : scope.skinnedInsert
            };

            inputs.iCheck(options);

            elem.on('ifChanged', function(event) { scope.$digest(); });

            scope.$watchCollection(
                function() { //The collection that will be checked for changes
                    var result = [];
                    inputs.each(function(index, el) {
                        result.push($(el).prop('checked'));
                    });
                    return result;
                },
                function() { // What happens when the collection changed
                    inputs.iCheck('update');// Notify our plugin
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

I thought that I might be on the wrong scope and tried getting the scope via angular.element(event.target).scope(), but that didn't change anything.

The HTML

```
<ul skinned="flat-grey">
    <li data-ng-click="checktest = true"><input id="1" type="checkbox" ng-model="checktest" /><label for="1">Label_1</label></li>
    <li><input id="2" type="checkbox" /><label for="2">Label_2</label></li>
    <li><input id="3" type="checkbox" /><label for="3">Label_3</label></li>
    <li><input id="4" type="checkbox" /><label for="4">Label_4</label></li>
    <li><input id="5" type="checkbox" /><label for="5">Label_5</label></li>
</ul>
```

When updating the model via ng-click iCheck picks it up, but not the other way around.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/MoTz9PmL0rLZ1kmDy9fJ

Comment: clicking on li and always making model true isn't going to help. Also the plugin custom events should be bound to input, not `<ul>`

Comment: This isn't an actual use case. That was only to illustrate the problem.

You are right the event is probably better on the inputs, but even with that change it won't fix the problem.

Comment: personally I would create directive for the input only, not for set. But then , my preference is do this with CSS and forget plugin altogether

Comment: The issue with CSS is that it can't style those elements reliable across browsers. I have made a quick change here: http://plnkr.co/edit/q5naZ4S2aFvZWy1LQQy9?p=info , but that has no effect on updating the model that is attached to the input.

Comment: OK...try this. I like to remove isolated scopes when they aren't needed. This is working based solely on `attrs`  http://plnkr.co/edit/Z9IWDRLtXIUpTnKdmuUi?p=preview

Comment: That is probably the right to go about this. I am still getting grips on when and where to use directives and actually replacing the inputs didn't occur to me. Thanks :)

Comment: replacing was just an addiitonal touch...was working without replace also. With forms especially isolated scopes become a pain due to validation object